# How to get input values to update when reordering items in Elm update

Tags: dom, elm

I'm running the following code within Elm reactor (0.18) and after clicking the "Switch" button, the labels correctly reorder but the text entered in the boxes does not.  The debugger shows that the values in the model are correct, but it appears as if only part of the DOM is getting updated.  What am I doing wrong?

(Note: This appears to happen in Firefox 52.0.2 and Chrome 57.0.2987.11, both on Ubuntu 16.04)

```
module App exposing (..)

import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (onInput, onClick)


type Position
    = First
    | Second


type alias Model =
    { value1 : String, value2 : String, order : List Position }


type Msg
    = SwitchOrder
    | SetFirst String
    | SetSecond String


init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
    ( { value1 = "", value2 = "", order = [ First, Second ] }, Cmd.none )


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        SwitchOrder ->
            ( { model | order = List.reverse model.order }, Cmd.none )

        SetFirst new_value ->
            ( { model | value1 = new_value }, Cmd.none )

        SetSecond new_value ->
            ( { model | value2 = new_value }, Cmd.none )


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.none


labeledInput : Model -> Position -> Html Msg
labeledInput model position =
    case position of
        First ->
            div []
                [ label [] [ text "First" ]
                , input [ onInput SetFirst ] [ text model.value1 ]
                ]

        Second ->
            div []
                [ label [] [ text "Second" ]
                , input [ onInput SetSecond ] [ text model.value2 ]
                ]


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ List.map (labeledInput model) model.order |> div []
        , button [ onClick SwitchOrder ] [ text "Switch" ]
        ]


main : Program Never Model Msg
main =
    program
        { init = init
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        , view = view
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set the value of an Input use [Html.Attributes.value](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html-Attributes#value) not `text`

```
import Html.Attributes exposing (value)

...

First ->
    div []
        [ label [] [ text "First" ]
        , input [ onInput SetFirst, value model.value1 ] []
        ]
```